# Blockchain explorer for indyscan

Tags: docker-compose

I want to create the blockchain explorer for the sovrin network.
currently indyscan repo is there https://github.com/Patrik-Stas/indyscan.
I can not get started with indyscan by following the instruction in the given repo.
IndyPool + IndyScan on localhost....first command 'docker-compose up'  gives an error.

*"Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
parent. Are you in the right directory?
Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml, compose.yml, compose.yaml
"*

Can anybody help me with how to get started with HL Indy + explorer?

Most of the repo are related to fabric only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am also new with IndyScan but was able to get things going with `docker-compose -f docker-compose.es.yml -f docker-compose.yml up -d`.  Make sure that you are in the `start` directory in the repo.

Comment: There is a makefile that defines targets for starting and stopping. 
You can use `make up` to start all containers wich in turn will run the command @aaronr mentioned